# DIV Animation after Jquery .html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a UL of DIV's. The when the DIVs are clicked the page should animate slide open displaying information about the topic clicked. This works fine. I have now added code see below, to add a page 2 that will overwrite the divs above with new topics.  On page load you can click the divs to see the information. But after selecting next page, when clicking on the divs. nothing happens. For testing i have only rearranged the divs. so i know the id names are the same. I am fairly new at this but i feel as if there may be an easier way to do this. Also i have wondered if in the code to animate the upper and lower div. after its changed would it be `upperhidden` now? Any help would be appreciated. I feel as if i did a horrible job explaining what to do. but i can provide what ever is needed.

UPDATE:
Thanks. I will try this again. i have a site. that has 2 rows of 3. These are images such as:

password | HMS | pluto
citrix | java | email
button1

say you click password the page opens like below the top row animates up and bottom row animates down and information opens between them

password | HMS | pluto
       pw reset info
citrix | java | email
button1

This aspect all works correctly. I have added the code that will replace the top and bottom rows. for testing i have it where the bottom goes to top and vise versa. When `button1` is click screen changes like this.

citrix | java| email
password | HMS | pluto
button2

Once at this lay out say you click password it should open to show this

citrix | java | email
    PW reset Info
password | HMS | pluto
button2

But this operation is not working. once the items are changed from the `jquery code $('#upper').html(jQuery("#upperhidden").html());` when you make a selection the divs do not open to show the information. Note button 2 sets the divs back to as the are on page load. Even going back to main they will not open/raise/lower.

Maybe this explains the question a little better.

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var divClone = $("#upper").clone();
  var divClone1 = $("#lower").clone();
  $("#button1").hide();
  $("#button1").click(function(event) {
    $("#car").show();
    $("#button1").hide()
    $("#upper").replaceWith(divClone.clone());
    $("#lower").replaceWith(divClone1.clone());
  });
});


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#car").click(function() { 
    $('#upper').html(jQuery("#upperhidden").html());
    $('#lower').html(jQuery("#lowerhidden").html());         
    $("#car").hide(); 
    $("#button1").show();
  });
});


 $(function()
  {
  var closed = true;
  $('.password').click(function()
                       {
    if (closed = true)
    {
      $("#upper").animate({'top' : '-200px'}, {duration: 400});
      closed = false;

      $("#maininfo").animate({'top' : '200px'}, {duration: 000});
      closed = false;

      $("#lower").animate({'top' : '400px'}, {duration: 400});
      closed = false;

      $("#filler").animate({'top' : '400px'}, {duration: 400});
      closed = false;

      var output = document.getElementById("maininfo");
      var sentence = '<h4>PASSWORD RESET</h4>';

      var open = true;
      output.innerHTML = sentence;
    }
    else
    {

    }
  });
});

function callShell(){
  var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
  objShell.run('rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation');
}
```

```css
CSS


#upper, #lower {
  background: #849794;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

#upper {
  /* For IE */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=180, Color='#000000')";
  /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=180, Color='#000000');
}

#upper ul {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

#upper ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 230px;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#lower {
  background: #849794;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* For IE */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=0, Color='#000000')";
  /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=0, Color='#000000');
}

#lower ul {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

#lower ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 230px;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#filler {
  width: 100%;
  background: #849794;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}


.password {
  background: url(../images/pr1.png);
  background-size: 100%;
}

.password:hover {
  background: url(../images/pr2.png);
  background-size: 100%;
}

.password:active {
  background: url(../images/pr3.png);
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="upper">
        <ul id="upper1">
            <!-- TOP BUTTONS -->
            <li class="password"></li>
            <li class="enable"></li>
            <li class="abstract"></li>
            <!-- TOP BUTTONS -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="upperhidden" style="display:none">
        <ul>
            <!-- TOP BUTTONS PAGE 2 -->
            <li class="abstract"></li>
            <li class="citrix"></li>
            <li class="password"></li>
            <!-- TOP BUTTONS PAGE 2 -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="maininfo">
    </div>
    <div id="lower">
        <ul id="lower1">
            <!-- BOTTOM BUTTONS -->
            <li class="threem"></li>
            <li class="citrix"></li>
            <li class="cerner"></li>
            <!-- BOTTOM BUTTONS -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="lowerhidden" style="display:none">
        <ul>
            <!-- BOTTOM BUTTONS PAGE 2 -->
            <li class="password"></li>
            <li class="enable"></li>
            <li class="abstract"></li>
            <!-- BOTTOM BUTTONS PAGE 2 -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="filler">
        <button id="car">Next Page</button>
        <button id="button1">Prev Page</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please remove the ugly separating comments. No one needs to see that. Either split it into different files or use a post processor.

Comment: i know you are looking to "roll your own"....but since you are starting out...can you start with something already done and then modify it?  there are a number of prebuilt jquery menus, such as [http://jqueryui.com/menu/#icons](http://jqueryui.com/menu/#icons) or [http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/36-eye-catching-jquery-navigation-menus/](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/36-eye-catching-jquery-navigation-menus/)

Answer (score 4):

the only biggie i see is in the JS code

```
if (closed = true)
```

you are missing an =

```
if (closed == true)
```

but, yes, there is an easier way to do this without the  "UL of DIV's"

Comment: I see what you mean here. And it was working both ways. but the animations will not happen after this the function to change upper to upperhidden and lower to lowerhidden

Comment: can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?  maybe i can help more

Comment: Updated original question. Hope it is more understandable. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

use `$('.password').on('click', function() { //do stuff here; });` instead of `$('.password').click()`. the `.on('click', ...)` function recognizes dynamically added elements to the DOM so the click will register for your newly cloned elements

**EDIT - simple demo below** http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/431/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.password').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $('.content').fadeOut(500);
         $('.bottom').animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, { duration: 1500, queue: false } );
            $('.top').animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, { duration: 1500, queue: false });
            var html = '';
            
            $(this).removeClass('open');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $('.bottom').animate({ marginTop: "+140px" }, { duration: 1500, queue: false });
            $('.top').animate({ marginTop: "-70px" }, { duration: 1500, queue: false });
            var html = 'this is the password stuff that goes in this place.';
            $('.content').html(html).fadeIn(3000);
        }        
    });
    $('.btn1').on('click', function() {
     var newtop = $('.top').clone(true).removeClass('top').addClass('bottom');
        var newbot = $('.bottom').clone(true).removeClass('bottom').addClass('top');
        $('.upper').html('').append(newbot);
        $('.lower').html('').append(newtop);
    });
});
```

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.main {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.btnDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.content {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="upper">
        <ul class="top">
            <li class="password">password</li>
            <li class="hms">HMS</li>
            <li class="pluto">pluto</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="lower">
        <ul class="bottom">
            <li class="citrix">citrix</li>
            <li class="java">java</li>
            <li class="email">email</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btnDiv">
    <button class="btn btn1">switch</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I thought it was something with the way it was dynamically adding the elements. Using IE's tools on click it shows the correct selected object.   shows that li class password is selected on click.

Comment: @CodyJones, i added a simple demo